# Select between two dates if one date contains null

Tags: mysql, sql, date, null

Hi kind folks of stackoverflow!

I want this query to check if a room(rum, in swedish), is available between two dates. However, I would like the query to first check if the room has been checked out, otherwise use fDatum AND tDatum. If the room has been checked out, then it should use fDatum and checkUt.

In the database we store both when the room has been booked from and to (fDatum, tDatum), as well as which date the room has checked in and out (checkIn, checkUt).

EDIT: The output will show the room numbers of the rooms that are not booked between 2021-10-12 and 2021-10-14, along with the room type (single, double, family).

Below you will find the code in use right now. But if a guest checks out earlier than 2021-10-12, the room may still show up as booked if the room was booked to the 2021-10-12. The guest must still pay for the room for the 2021-10-12, but if the guest checked out early, the hotel wants to be able to rent out the room.

```
Select rumNr, rumTyp
From Rum
Where RumNr NOT IN (Select RumNr
                    From BokningRum
                    Where fDatum BETWEEN '2021-10-12' AND '2021-10-14'
                    OR tDatum BETWEEN '2021-10-12' AND '2021-10-14')
GROUP BY rumNr
;
```

so I want the code to work like this instead:

```
Select rumNr, rumTyp
From Rum
Where RumNr NOT IN (Select RumNr
From BokningRum
Where fDatum BETWEEN '2021-10-12' AND '2021-10-14'
                    OR checkUt BETWEEN '2021-10-12' AND '2021-10-14')
                    -- If checkUt is null, then do
                    -- Where fDatum BETWEEN '2021-10-12' AND '2021-10-14'
                    -- OR tDatum BETWEEN '2021-10-12' AND '2021-10-14')
GROUP BY rumNr
;
```

Comment: Hi Jocke, welcome to Stack Overflow! I think it would help others answer your question if you provide an expected input and output.

Comment: so if checkIn is not null, it is the beginning date for the booking and otherwise fDatum is?  and similarly, if checkUt is not null, it is the ending date and otherwise tDatum is?

Comment: if you are looking for rooms that are available for all of a date range, you can't use between, since if it is booked for the entire date range plus some at the beginning and end, the from and to dates will not be in your range.

Comment: also, shouldn't a room booked through a given day be available for checking in that same day?

Comment: @ysth Kind off... We don't really care about the checkIn date for this query since the hotel won't give up a room if the person will come just a day later (but he will still pay for the day he missed). So fDatum is fromDate and itDatum is toDate. Those are the dates that the room is booked and can not be null. checkIn and checkUt(checkOut) can be null. So the checkUt should be searched for, along with fDatum, if the room has been checked out and therefor has a date. If the room is booked in the future, then it wont have a checkIn/Ut date and therefor it should search fDatum along with tDatum.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (no images.) i.e. [mcve] - make it easy to assist you!

Comment: most simply, you want to check `coalesce(checkUt,tDatum)`, but as I said above, I don't think your approach to checking the from and to dates instead of checking for overlap (or excluding having one person check out in the morning and another check in in the afternoon) are correct for your stated purpose

Answer (score 0):

```
Select rumNr, rumTyp
From Rum
Where RumNr NOT IN (
Select RumNr
                    From BokningRum
                    Where 
                    case when !isnull(checkUt) then
                     fDatum BETWEEN '2021-10-12' AND '2021-10-14'                    
                    OR  tDatum BETWEEN '2021-10-12' AND '2021-10-14'
                    else
                     fDatum BETWEEN '2021-10-12' AND '2021-10-14'  
                    end
                    )
GROUP BY rumNr;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Guram, I managed to solve it. I know my explanation was not great but thank you all so much for your help. This is the final query that will earn me those extra marks.

Thanks again!

```
Select rumNr, rumTyp
From Rum
Where RumNr NOT IN (
Select RumNr
                    From BokningRum
                    Where 
                    case when checkUt<tDatum then
                     (fDatum BETWEEN '2021-10-12' AND '2021-10-14'                    
                    OR  checkUt BETWEEN '2021-10-12' AND '2021-10-14')
                    else
                    ( fDatum BETWEEN '2021-10-12' AND '2021-10-14'
                     OR  tDatum BETWEEN '2021-10-12' AND '2021-10-14')
                    end
                    )
GROUP BY rumNr;
```

The output will be the rooms that are available for booking those dates.

```
rumNr,rumTyp
1,Enkel
2,Enkel
3,Enkel
4,Enkel
5,Enkel
6,Enkel
7,Enkel
8,Enkel
9,Enkel
10,Enkel
11,Dubbel
12,Dubbel
13,Dubbel
14,Dubbel
16,Dubbel
17,Dubbel
18,Dubbel
19,Dubbel
20,Dubbel
21,Dubbel
23,Dubbel
25,Dubbel
26,Dubbel
27,Dubbel
28,Dubbel
29,Dubbel
30,Dubbel
31,Familje
32,Familje
```

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=634ceec21ea7d52a9b890b7baad3e410)

You may have a couple of problems in your solution.

One is the overlap logic isn't correct and misses some cases, as @ysth suggested.

The other is your use of `GROUP BY`, which is either not necessary, because `rumNr` is unique (or the `primary key`) in the `Rum` table or the `SELECT` list is not valid, since `rumType` would not be `functionally dependent` on the `GROUP BY` terms.

Here's a suggested solution, which should handle the missed cases as well.

Note: I've continued to use your logic for the `tDatum` and `checkUt` day in the range, where we will prevent booking of a room on the day another person is checking out.

```
SELECT rumNr, rumTyp
  FROM Rum
 WHERE RumNr NOT IN (
        SELECT RumNr
          FROM BokningRum
         WHERE fDatum                    <= '2021-10-14'
           AND COALESCE(checkUt, tDatum) >= '2021-10-12'
        )
;
```

If we want to allow overlap of the first and last days of the booked range, we can use this:

```
SELECT rumNr, rumTyp
  FROM Rum
 WHERE RumNr NOT IN (
        SELECT RumNr
          FROM BokningRum
         WHERE fDatum                    <  '2021-10-14'
           AND COALESCE(checkUt, tDatum) >  '2021-10-12'
        )
;
```

I'll provide test data below.

**The result of the proposed SQL above #1:**

[image]

**The result of the proposed SQL above #2:**

[image]

**The result of your original SQL, assuming rumNr is the `PRIMARY KEY` in `Rum`:**

[image]

**Notice `rumNr = 7` in the result.**

Your original SQL, with `GROUP BY` removed, with the assumption that `rumNr` is `unique` or the `primary key` of `Rum`.

```
Select rumNr, rumTyp
  From Rum
 Where RumNr NOT IN (
             Select RumNr
               From BokningRum
              Where 
                  case when checkUt<tDatum then
                       ( fDatum BETWEEN '2021-10-12' AND '2021-10-14'                    
                    OR  checkUt BETWEEN '2021-10-12' AND '2021-10-14')
                  else
                       ( fDatum BETWEEN '2021-10-12' AND '2021-10-14'
                    OR   tDatum BETWEEN '2021-10-12' AND '2021-10-14')
                  end
             )
-- GROUP BY rumNr
;
```

**The setup:**

```
CREATE TABLE Rum        (rumNr int, rumTyp VARCHAR(10));
CREATE TABLE BokningRum (RumNr int, fDatum DATE, tDatum DATE, checkUt DATE);

INSERT INTO Rum VALUES
   ( 1, 'type1')
 , ( 2, 'type1')
 , ( 3, 'type1')
 , ( 4, 'type1')
 , ( 5, 'type1')
 , ( 6, 'type1')
 , ( 7, 'type1')
 , ( 8, 'type1')
 , ( 9, 'type1')
 , (10, 'type1')
 , (30, 'type2')
;

INSERT INTO BokningRum VALUES
   ( 1, '2021-10-12', '2021-10-14', null)
 , ( 2, '2021-10-12', '2021-10-14', '2021-10-13')
 , ( 3, '2021-10-12', '2021-10-14', '2021-10-14')
 , ( 4, '2021-10-12', '2021-10-14', '2021-10-15')
 , ( 5, '2021-10-11', '2021-10-13', null)
 , ( 6, '2021-10-13', '2021-10-13', null)
 , ( 7, '2021-10-11', '2021-10-15', null)
 , (10, '2021-10-08', '2021-10-12', null)
;
```